# Как правильно передать данные сокет-клиенту?

Tags: java, android

Есть активити, которое запускает AsyncTask:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

SocketAsync SocketAsync = new SocketAsync();
ConfigSocket config = new ConfigSocket();

Button btnEnter;
Button btnFight;

//выводит все элементы этого активити
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //убираю ActionBar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //убираю заголовок приложения
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //подключаем лауер-файл с элементами
    //находим эти элементы по ID
    btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
    btnFight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFight);

    // присваиваем обработчик кнопкам
    btnEnter.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFight.setOnClickListener(this);

    SocketAsync.execute();
 }

//обработчик нажатий на кнопки
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // по id определеяем кнопку, вызвавшую этот обработчик
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnEnter:
            config.setSOCKET_MESSAGE("12345");
            break;
        case  R.id.btnFight:
            config.setSOCKET_MESSAGE("12345");
            break;
    }
}
```

код AsyncTask:

```
 public class SocketAsync extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, Void> {

public Socket socket;
public String message;
ConfigSocket config = new ConfigSocket();

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    //конект с сервером
    try {
        if (config.getSOCKET_CONNECTED() == false) {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(config.SERVER_ADDR);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, config.SERVER_PORT);
            config.setSOCKET_CONNECTED(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //создает новый поток для отправки сообщений
    Thread threadWrite = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            send(socket);
        }
    });
    threadWrite.start(); // запускаем на отправку

    //пока есть конект с сервером, цикл ждет приема сообщений
    while (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
        //Message m = new Message();
        //m.what = 2;
        try {
            //переменная для получение данных
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String st = null;
            st = input.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    threadWrite.stop();
    return null;
}

protected void send(Socket socket) {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    //пока есть конект с сервером, цикл ждет сообщение на отправку
    while (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
         if (config.getSOCKET_MESSAGE() = null) {
            //Log.d("Send Message", config.SOCKET_MESSAGE);
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                out.println(config.getSOCKET_MESSAGE());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
            config.setSOCKET_MESSAGE(null);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //если связь разорвалась....
    if (socket == null || !socket.isConnected()) {
        config.setSOCKET_CONNECTED(false);
}
}
```

и есть вот такой класс:

```
public class ConfigSocket {

boolean SOCKET_CONNECTED = false;
String SERVER_ADDR = "192.168.1.23";
int SERVER_PORT = 8888;
String SOCKET_MESSAGE = null;

public String getSOCKET_MESSAGE() { //геттер SOCKET_MESSAGE
    return this.SOCKET_MESSAGE;
}

public void setSOCKET_MESSAGE(String SOCKET_MESSAGE) { //сеттер SOCKET_MESSAGE
    this.SOCKET_MESSAGE = SOCKET_MESSAGE;
}

public boolean getSOCKET_CONNECTED() { //геттер SOCKET_CONNECTED
    return this.SOCKET_CONNECTED;
}

public void setSOCKET_CONNECTED(boolean SOCKET_CONNECTED) { //сеттер SOCKET_CONNECTED
    this.SOCKET_CONNECTED = SOCKET_CONNECTED;
}
}
```

Помогите разобраться. Вот как я думаю. `AsyncTask` запускает новый поток, где коннектится с сервером (о чем сервер мне сообщает, что новый клиент успешно законнектился) и пока не разорвано соединение по циклу должен ждать входящую информацию. И запускается еще один поток, который должен отправлять сообщение на сервер. Его цикл должен сканить переменную `SOCKET_MESSAGE` c класса `ConfigSocket`, если она не `null`, тогда отравлять сообщение серверу. По кнопке в активити я задаю переменной значение, но сообщение не отправляется. А если перед запуском приложения в `ConfigSocket` заранее прописать значение `SOCKET_MESSAGE`, тогда оно будет оправлено.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю не так и как правильно это все реализовать? Потому что я уже 3-й день пытаюсь в этом разобраться.
Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас используются два разных экземпляра `ConfigSocket` в `SocketAsync` и `MainActivity`, вам нужно передать экземпляр `ConfigSocket` в конструкторе или в параметрах `execute`

Также нужно отметить, что у вас доступ к `SOCKET_MESSAGE` никак не синхронизирован и использовать `Thread.stop` не рекомендуется, а в вашем случае ещё и бессмысленно (если уж до этой строчки дойдет, то сокет будет закрыт и второй поток выйдет сам, без принуждения)

Comment: я вчера об этом читал, но там общие примеры. Если Вам не сложно, пожалуйста, покажите это в коде на моем примере с комментариями, что бы я раз и на всегда понял как это делать. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: боюсь, что лучше вам задавать конкретные вопросы - исправьте ошибку с двумя экземплярами ConfigSocket и попытайтесь сделать доступ к общим переменным только через syncronized блоки, если что-то будет не так - создайте ещё один вопрос

Comment: спасибо огромное, я разобрался с синхронизацией и передачей одного екземпляра класса другим потокам.

Comment: еще один последний вопрос. У меня стоит условие (socket != null && socket.isConnected()  ), но когда я закрываю сервер-программу или жена выключает роутер, то оно все равно считает что socket.isConnected() = true. Подскажите как правильно проверить вот такой разрыв подключения.

Comment: Судя по документации isConnected означает что удалось связаться с сервером, что с сокетом после этого происходит - уже не важно, всегда будет возвращаться true. Скорее всего нужно воспользоваться методом isClosed

Comment: Спасибо, сегодня попробую.